# How to return empty response from root URL in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app using `djangorestframework`. I want to return an empty response or nothing if the root URL is called. Below is my code.

```
url(r'^$', HttpResponse(''), name="redirect_to_somepage")
```

> Expected output: [] or {}

Comment: Note that the second argument shouldn't be a rendered response, but a view (or callable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a get function in your view.

**view.py**

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({}, status=204)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(regex=r'^$', view=MyView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Comment: Why a JsonResponse? Why not `HttpResponse(status=204)`?

Comment: @9769953 we can use any of it.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Exception Value: name 'View' is not defined

Comment: @SachinSingh Need to import `View` class. Answer is updated.

Comment: it worked but what should I import if I want to use `HttpResponse(status=204)`?

Comment: @SachinSingh Import this `from django.http import HttpResponse`